# Is the Standard hydrogen electrode potential at T other than 298 K also zero?

Tags: electrochemistry, reduction-potential

> The standard hydrogen electrode potential by conventional at 298 K is taken to be 0.00 volts.

This is what I have been taught. It talks about SHE at 298 K, so is the hydrogen electrode potential at a temperature other than 298 kelvin also defined to be zero ? If not, how do we calculate at any other temperature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the definition used by [IUPAC](https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.S05917), the standard electrode potential $E^\circ$ of the standard hydrogen electrode is zero at all temperatures.

> For solutions in protic solvents, the universal reference electrode for which, under standard conditions, the standard electrode potential ($\ce{H+}/\ce{H2}$) is zero at all temperatures.

The absolute electrode potential $E^\circ(\mathrm{abs})$, however, depends on temperature. Its value can be calculated from thermodynamic quantities (e.g. $\Delta G^\circ$). The recommended value for $T=298.15\ \mathrm K$ is $E^\circ(\mathrm{abs})=4.44(2)\ \mathrm V$.

Comment: For those (like me) who have never heard of absolute electrode potential: It uses the free electron in a vacuum as reference point, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_electrode_potential

Comment: Wait, if the standard electrode potential is zero at all temperatures, what would the electrical potential be of a cell where each half-cell was at a different temperature?